# Finding subgraphs of particular shape in graphs with edges of two colours

Tags: graphs-and-networks

My typical task: in the graph

[image]

must find a subgraph of shape

[image]

so that edge colors match. Here by subgraphs, **full** subgraphs are meant: if a subgraph contains endpoints of an edge, it must contain the whole edge too.

What would be an efficient way to do it in Mathematica?

On request, here are codes for the graphs:

```
matogra[m_]:= Graph3D[
       Map[
        With[{i=First[#],j=Last[#]},
         Style[i<->j,If[m[[i,j]]==1,Red,Blue]]
        ]&,
        Select[Subsets[Range[Length[m]],{2}],m[[#[[1]]]][[#[[2]]]]!=0&]
      ]
     ];

matogra[
 {
  { 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1,-1, 0,-1, 0},
  { 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1,-1, 0, 0, 0,-1,-1, 0, 0},
  { 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0,-1},
  { 0, 0, 0, 2, 0,-1, 1, 0,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  { 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0,-1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,-1,-1},
  { 0, 1, 0,-1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0,-1,-1, 0, 0},
  { 0,-1, 0, 1,-1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  { 0, 0,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1,-1, 0,-1, 0},
  { 0, 0, 0,-1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0,-1,-1},
  {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0,-1, 0,-1},
  {-1,-1, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0,-1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0},
  { 0,-1,-1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0, 0,-1, 1, 2, 0, 1},
  {-1, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0,-1,-1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1},
  { 0, 0,-1, 0,-1, 0, 0, 0,-1,-1, 0, 1, 1, 2}
 }
]

matogra[
 {
  { 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1},
  { 1, 2, 0, 0, 0,-1,-1, 0},
  { 0, 0, 2, 0,-1, 0, 0,-1},
  { 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0,-1, 0},
  { 0, 0,-1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0},
  { 0,-1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0,-1},
  { 0,-1, 0,-1, 0, 0, 2, 0},
  {-1, 0,-1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 2}
 }
]
```

Comment: can you post the code that produced the input graph?

Comment: @kglr Sorry, should think of it. Will do in a minute